# MSSQL Stored Procedure not reading parameter correctly

Tags: c#, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ado.net

I am learning/building an API with AWS RDS/Lambda/API Gateway. The DB is MSSQL as we have historically used SQL databases and the Lambda is being written in C# (I'm also new to C#) within Visual Studio.

I have setup a test database with a simple dummy user table and written a basic SP to get data. The SP takes a single optional parameter of 'User' and returns all columns where that User is found, or all if no parameter issued.

Tested within MSSMS and the SP works both with and without parameter. I have written the function in Visual Studio and tested tested with the Mock Lambda Test Tool. If no parameter is sent in, then I get a full list of users. However, when I try to pass the parameter the reader executes but returns no result. I have checked and triple checked the parameter name and value and both should be valid. I can't see why this would happen? I have done this thousands of times in VB.net and never had an issue.

Code as follows:

SP:

```
USE [playground]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetUsers]    Script Date: 22/02/2021 14:29:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]

    @User varchar(60) = null

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM PlayUsers
    WHERE (@User IS NULL OR UName = @User)

END
```

C# Code:

```
public static class Function
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Run a simple SP with optinal parameter to prove concept
        /// </summary>
        public static object FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var users = "";
            Console.WriteLine("*** Starting function ***");
            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUsers", conn)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", "BearDown");
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "BearDown";

                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            users += ToJson(rdr);
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception thrown: {ex}");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** End function  ***");
            }

            return users;
        }

        public static string ToJson(this SqlDataReader rdr)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

            using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();

                    int fields = rdr.FieldCount;

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
                    {
                        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(rdr.GetName(i));
                        jsonWriter.WriteValue(rdr[i]);
                    }

                    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
                }

                jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();

                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have tried both .Add and .AddWithValue to add the parameter but neither seems to pass the parameter. I have stepped through the code and can see that it does run through the SQL Reader fine and no exception is hit, but it never finds any results.

Adding a watch to rdr it shows: "Enumeration yielded no results" when a parameter is used. But again, both values work fine when executing the SP in MSSMS.

** UPDATE **
After hacking around with this, I have found that replacing

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            users = rdr.ToJson();
                        }
                    }
```

With just

```
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                      users = rdr.ToJson();
                    }
```

Works as required. I guess I'll wrap that in a if (rdr.HasRows) and looks like a solution.

Comment: FYI, when you have `using (SqlConnection conn ...` you don't need to call `conn.Close()` and/or `conn.Dispose()`, as that is handled by the `using`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thank you, I wasn’t sure. Old habit from my vb.net days

Comment: Are you getting every row from database?  Check carefully to see if in c# if you are seeing "BearDown"

Comment: Your code looks correct, although you should use `Add` and pass the correct length. Also kinda odd to use `StringBuilder` but not hang onto it for the rest of the rows. When you say it steps through the reader, does it actually loop as if it's receiving rows, or does it jump the loop?

Comment: @TonyLaw: Using `using` was the right way to do it in VB.NET as well, for what it's worth.  Using `AddWithValue` for a parameter is generally frowned upon.  It _usually_ works, but occasionally can surprise you.  Take a look at https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/, for an example

Comment: @jdweng yes, without the parameter passed the results fetch every row and within that, 'BearDown' is in the UName. With parameter added all I get returned is []

Comment: @Flydog57 Ok, thanks. Will switch back to .Add and pass the correct length.

Comment: Ok. So I have narrowed it down by running a SQL trace on the SP and I can see that the value is being passed into the SP. I've checked rdr.HasRows and it's returning true and in the rdr.Read actually logged rdr["UName"] and it is returning the correct value. So clearly the SP is being run and returning the correct result. But it falls over when running through rdr.Read AND there is only 1 row returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `rdr.Read()` ("advance the reader to the next record") in your `FunctionHandler` and then again in the `ToJson` function you call from there ... I don't think that's the intended behaviour? You are allways skipping one record there ... my suggestion is to try without `rer.Read()` in `FunctionHandler`.